# I need to run a range of IDs into my query to get the name, Parent, and Primary Address from Accounts

Tags: soql, query, bind-variable

When I enter the following code, I keep getting the error message

> Bind variables only allowed in Apex code

I am unsure how to make it so I can enter multiple IDs and get back the information I am looking for.

```
Select id, name, Primary_Parent_vod__c, Primary_Address

from Account 

Where ID = ('1jjfi4945uhh00000', '8350000grgfvdsvg')
```

Comment: You're going to need to [edit] your question to include more details. Where/how are you running this query (e.g. "from the developer console"). Is this the _exact_ query that you're running? Is it a dynamic query (i.e. are you passing it into `database.query()` in Apex)?

Comment: I am running this query with salesforce inspector data export to export the information from our saleforce database. This is the exact query I am currently running, it works when only one ID is entered, but I am getting the error message when I attempt to add more.

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to call your query in **Developer Console** or in **Apex code**, you should use next one :

```java
Select id, name, Primary_Parent_vod__c, Primary_Address
           from Account 
           Where ID IN ('1jjfi4945uhh00000', '8350000grgfvdsvg')
```

If you want to make it dynamic use this one :

```java
List<String> accountIds = new List<String>{'1jjfi4945uhh00000','8350000grgfvdsvg'};

List<Account> accounts = [Select id, name, Primary_Parent_vod__c, Primary_Address 
         from Account 
         Where ID IN : acccountIds];
```